# Moving an object in Android without user interaction and with the ability to get location

Tags: android

I am trying to move an object but I want to get its location.
I tried using animation, but I can't get the location:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter( true );
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

I also tried using object animators and I can get the location but the speed could be changed from developer options in Android:

```
move.animate().setListener(movinglist).x((click.getWidth() - move.getWidth())).setDuration(time).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use hidden api to access valueanimator duration scale and set it to 1x on the avtivity oncreate and onresume